# I want to check if the item is in the array/list and if it is then write that down if not then tell them it is not in there

Tags: c#

so if i start my code everything is fine but when i get to the part where it asks to choose a attachment i write down the one that is in the list but it just says it is not in there what am  i doing wronk?

```
  Console.WriteLine("Do you want any attachments on your gun?");
  if(Console.ReadLine() == "Yes")
  {
         attachments.ToList().ForEach(i=> Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
         Console.WriteLine("Choose A Attachment" + "\n");
         string q = Console.ReadLine();
         if (q != attachments.ToList().ToString())
         {
              Console.WriteLine("not found");
         }
         else if (q == attachments.ToList().ToString())
         {
             Console.WriteLine("attachment added");       
         }


  }
```

Comment: You're converting attachments to a list, then checking your input against the list as a string, instead of each element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (q != attachments.ToList().ToString())
```

should be:

```
if (!attachments.Contains(q)) // You may need a .ToList() before .Contains
```

and

```
else if (q == attachments.ToList().ToString())
```

should be:

```
else
```